# RecyclerView - вставить текст в сетку с изображениями

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать в RecyclerView , чтобы изображения были разделены неким текстом(например с датой), как на рисунке? В примерах что я видел просто сетка из изображений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поищите, на гите есть библиотека: recyclerview with headers - похоже, то, что вам нужно

Comment: https://github.com/truizlop/SectionedRecyclerView

Comment: Можно без использование библиотеки. А использовать несколько viewholder в recyclerView. И черех GridLayoutManager указать для фотографий чтоб их было 3 в ряд